# Iterate over nodes in a tree

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, tree-traversal

I want to make an iterator that can handle my selfmade structs:

```
struct node {
int n; //data element
node * parent;
node * left;
node * right;  
node (int elem): n(elem){ //create root
     parent = NULL; left = NULL; right = NULL;
}
node (int elem, node* p): n(elem), parent(p) { //addchild
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL; 
}
node(int elem, node * p, node * l, node * r): n(elem), parent(p), left(l), right(r){ //insert element
}
};
```

First of all, is this possible? If yes: how do I start to make the iterator that traverses the tree. If not: what do you suggest for me to do if I want to access data elements in the list.

Comment: Are you looking for algorithms in general? [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) the wikipedia on tree traversal.

Comment: no not really, I want a data structure to keep pointers to classes. Like I would make a list of pointers to a certain object. But I need a tree representation.

Comment: Do you know a good page where it shows me how to start making an iterator to traverse the tree?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Hint: Your iterator, when it advances, should go to the parent and figure out whether it's a left child or right child of that parent. That will tell you where to go next.

Comment: Check the address of parents right node and left node and check wether they are equal to my own address?

Comment: Since it's an iterator, it's not "my own address", it's "the address of the node I'm currently pointing to".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given the node structure you've outlined with a `right` pointer (which presumably points to the next node in traversal order), implementing a forward iterator should be quie easy.

The *basic* idea is something like this:

```
template <class Node>
class iterator { 
    Node *pos;
public:
    iterator(Node *tree = nullptr) : pos(tree) {}
    iterator operator++() { pos = pos->right; return *this; }
    Node &operator*() { return *pos; }
    bool operator!=(iterator const &other) const { return pos != other.pos; }
};
```

There is a little more than that involved in a real iterator though. In particular, you normally (always?) want to specify things like the `value_type`, `reference_type` and category of the iterator. Most of these are pretty close to pure boilerplate though, and you can handle most of them by deriving from `std::iterator`.

You also (typically) want to support a few more operations than I've shown here, such as post-fix increment, `operator==`, etc. Given this as a "framework", I think filling in those blanks should be fairly straightforward though.

I should probably also point out the existence of the [Boost iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library. This simplifies the task of implementing an iterator (somewhat) and cuts down on the boilerplate you have to write (quite a bit).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: pos is an address of a node and the ++ operator determines the traversal of the tree?

Comment: In the constructor you set tree to the nullptr, why? I would create the iterator with the root node.

Comment: and how do I work with the operator*:
`node & a = *iter;
 a.methodofnode(); ` 
this doesn't work for me! Iter is: `node root;
 iterator<node> iter(node& root);`

Comment: The ctor lets you specify a pointer, or if you don't specify one, it defaults to a nullptr. Assuming reasonably sane usage of the `right` pointer, this will let a default-constructed pointer signal the end of iteration. Just like with most iterators, you use `*` to access the item the iterator points at.

Comment: node & a = *iter; I get error: invalid use of member, did you forget &.

Comment: I declared node root; than i want an iterator: iterator<node>(&root); which doesn't work(it says did you forget type), when I try  iterator<node> iter(node& root); it works.
Now node & a = *iter; is supposed to give me a reference to a node, but it gives me an error saying: invalid use of member! 
i'm stuck ..